# How to find out if an image is loaded?

Tags: python, django, image, django-views

I have a django project which is running (for example) on `localhost:8000`.

I have an image in this address `localhost:8000/static/test.jpg` . A user may open just this image by going to it's url and not open the containing page.

I want to find out if this image is loaded in a user's browser (by loading the containing page or just entering the image's url) and I want to get the request object of that request.

Can I have a method in my views just for that specific image? I searched through the internet but didn't find anything useful. any idea or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally. for example i have a file in `localjost:8000/media/1.jpg` and i want to get ip of the user who enters this url to load the `1.jpg`.

I added this line in my urls :
 `url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'project.views.serve','document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),` and i set the MEDIA_ROOT already. then in `project.views.serve` i called `django.views.static.serve` and i returned the result of that as a HttpResponse. i have a request argument in my `project.views.serve` and i did this to get the user's ip from that :

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
print ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about disallowing hotlinking? This can be easier - and more effectively - done with the webserver that runs in front of your Django server.

For some examples for Apache check out https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DisableImageHotLinking

Comment: No i'm not talking about that my friend. i just want to get the request.GET when the user enters the image's url

Answer (score 0):

This can be only by serving your images with your custom views. E.g you should write your own view that will return static resources, and you will not use a standard django static handler

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that serving static files in a production environment should not be handled by Django in the first place. From `contrib/staticfiles/views.py`:

> Views and functions for serving static files. These are only to be used during
>   development, and SHOULD NOT be used in a production setting.

If you do want to use this, then you could write a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/%27) hooking into `process_view` or `process_request` to do your stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

Your way goes fine but bot for a high traffic. In that case you can use `XSendFile` library witch works with Apache

Comment: you're right but i'm not facing with a high traffic ;) thanks by the way